# How to fix ValidationFailedException in liquibase checksum?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I am using liquibase with spring boot. I am having SQL changesets. I have not changed anything in the liquibase SQL scripts. but I am getting below error

> Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path
> resource: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:\r\n
> 1 change sets check sum\r\n
> liquibase/db/0001_sample.sql::sample1_2::admin was:
> 8:600cf084d9c1ea85df2ddaa4f7a8a309 but is now:
> 8:47d241e6e1636203501ec72cafe4e5b6\r\n",
> "class": "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException",

Below is my **0001_table1.sql**

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset admin:sample1_1
create table....
--rollback DROP TABLE tablename

--changeset admin:sample1_2
add column....
```

I think this is due to formatting changing from my IDE to another ide. But I like to fix it. I am not looking for clearing checksum. Please suggest how to handle when using plain SQL with liquibase.

**Note:** I have seen examples with xml version, but I am looking for SQL with liquibase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you can't really do that.  Once you've applied a changeset it records the checksum in the config database, any changes (even whitespace) will cause this validation error.  If you're using maven or gradle you can clear the checksums and they will be recomputed on the next run by using the clearChecksums goal on the liquibase plugin.

You should pay close attention, when you use the SQL option (via `<include file="` I presume), it DOES NOT differ the checksum on whitespace so there are probably other differences that you are not seeing.  If you're confident that the changes are inconsequential, add

```
--validCheckSum 8:47d241e6e1636203501ec72cafe4e5b6
```

to the header of your SQL file and this will tell liquibase that even though the original checksum was calculated as `8:600cf084d9c1ea85df2ddaa4f7a8a309`, `8:47d241e6e1636203501ec72cafe4e5b6` is also a valid checksum for this file.

Some good advice would be to have tighter control of these files using your RCS, otherwise you're going to be constantly fighting with this.

Comment: Thank you.. I am using <includeAll path="classpath:/liquibase/db/"/>. 

In this case I will include all the sql files in db folder.

Comment: Same thing applies, add the validCheckSum line to your sql that are failing to pass validation

Comment: is validCheckSum can be a random string? or it is a calculated value. Because I have to deploy across multiple environments?

Comment: The checksum will be the same in all environments provided the same input.  Your best bet is to ensure tighter control over these changesets, otherwise you're going to go crazy trying to keep up with the checksums

Answer (score 1):

In my case with additions to liquibase SQL scripts the same error was resolved by exploring the `databasechangelog` table and manually deleting the last record from it:

```
DELETE FROM public.databasechangelog WHERE id = 'id_you_discovered'
```